# Assuming a user sends his IP and port to another, why does WebRTC need a signaling server for a data connection?

Tags: javascript, networking, webrtc, p2p

In all serverless (not including ICE/STUN) implementations of WebRTC, that create a data connection, I've always noticed that the flow is:

- User 1 sends contact info to user 2.
- User 2 processes contact info and sends reponse to user 1.
- Users can now communicate.

What I don't understand is why do we need the second step? In desktop apps, the first step is enough, even if there's a NAT (due to STUN servers). Is this some WebRTC limitation? If so, why?

Comment: How does user 1 know his public contact info (maybe he's behind a router and knows only local intranet details)? How does user 1 know the contact details for user 2 (in order to send the contact details)? ... eventually, every contact protocol needs a contact directory or publishing service of some kind... any you might need to create NAT routing table entries somehow...

Comment: I'm assuming that user1 sends user2 a link through some chat service which is what I currently do. What I don't understand is why user2 needs to send an sdp back instead of just getting a connection.

As for the NAT routing, from what I know, this is done purely through the STUN server, so the SDP has nothing do with it. Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not certain about the details of your implementation, but in general User 2 would actively send a packet to User 1 in order to ["punch a hole" in the NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching)... that's assuming a UDP based WebRTC session.

Answer (score 1):

Besides ICE candidates, SDP contains information about codecs, tracks etc. Signaling server is needed as a channel to establish a connection between peers by exchanging such information.

Comment: Let's say that I only want a data connection, will this still be a problem? why?

Comment: Well, in this very case, when you need to send only data and both peers have public IP, then the answer has only a formal meaning.  But if one peer is behind NAT and another is not behind NAT, establishing a p2p connection depends on the user that is behind NAT. Let's suppose, user (A) who is behind "restricted" or "symmetric" NAT sends an offer to user B who is not behind NAT. User B answers with his transport info and tries to connect to User A but cannot do it as A is behind NAT. Then user A sends data packets to B so B now knows to which address and port he should send data.

Comment: In order to bypass the NAT, one can use a STUN server, without exchanging any other tokens except for server IP. This has been implemented in many networked games on desktop.

Maybe I'm missing something, but assuming that both sides use the same STUN server (first side can send the second the STUN address as well), this should still, theoretically, be possible.

Comment: then how do you solve encryption? The signaling exchange is just this, exchanging candidates, encryption and supported formats. It is *how* the user sends a message to another user and it requires a bidirectional exchange for security reasons.

Comment: Encryption is not enough for security, there's also the need for authentication of identity, which WebRTC already lacks. Let's assume, for our purposes, that I don't mind an unencrypted data connection. I don't mind having what I send over the data connection be visible to the whole world.

Comment: When both users are behind symmetric NAT, STUN is not enough to bypass it. That's why we need TURN server.